# Global gitignore - how to exclude a single specific folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to exclude all `.idea` files in a specific folder through a global .gitignore (located in `~/.gitignore_global`).

I tried to put a following lines there:

```
# assuming .gitignore_global understands absolute paths
/Users/<my home folder>/Desktop/Dev/**/.idea

# assuming .gitignore_global takes a location of global gitignore (~) as a root
Desktop/Dev/**/.idea
```

Neither seem to work (however, adding just `.idea` works, so this global gitignore is used by git - however, I don't want to ignore .idea for my personal projects in other folders).

How are global excludes supposed to work?

Which folder is considered by git as a 'root'? (in case of normal `.gitignore`, all paths are relative to a repository root, but global gitignore seems to work differently).

Thanks!

I'm on a Mac, git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)

EDIT: As per @torek:

> The global gitignore is treated as if it were in the root Git directory (the work-tree top level).

So, there is no way to accomplish this, as there is no way to check the path of a whole project.

Comment: As an alternative, you could put `!.idea/` rule in your personal project's `.gitignore`. That will cancel the ignore rule defined globally, and you will be able to commit your .idea directory

Comment: The global gitignore is treated *as if* it were in the root Git directory (the work-tree top level).

Comment: I.e., just `/.idea/` should work.

Comment: @torek Aha! This explains every behavior I didn't understand. And so, sadly, it isn't possible to accomplish what I want then.

Comment: @Antwane Thanks, it's a hack, but it seems like the only possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible with this workaround with these files:

##### ~/.gitconfig

```bash
[includeIf "gitdir:~/my-specific-repo/"]
  path = ~/tailored-gitconfig/my-specific-repo/gitconfig
```

##### ~/tailored-gitconfig/my-specific-repo/gitconfig

```bash
[core]
  excludesFile = ~/tailored-gitconfig/my-specific-repo/gitignore
```

##### ~/tailored-gitconfig/my-specific-repo/gitignore

```bash
file-to-ignore
folder-to-ignore
```

In this way, "global" gitignore kicks off only within certain path.

*`~/tailored-gitconfig` is an arbitrary path for the example.*

Comment: Great workaround, thanks. The only issue is that setting excludesFile to the tailored file overwrites the original `core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore_global` setting, so i have to copy the global gitignore file into each tailored gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

As per @torek in comments:

> The global gitignore is treated as if it were in the root Git directory (the work-tree top level).

So, there is no way to accomplish this, as there is no way to check the path of a whole project.